# symfony 2 - “error The option ”0“ does not exist.”

Tags: symfony, entity, formbuilder

Im using a2lix/TranslationFormBundle and Im trying to add an EntityType fiedl in.

I got this error when i try to build the form  :

```
 The option "0" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "inherit_data", "intention", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "virtual"
```

here's my  FormType

```
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
 use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tag', TextType::class)
        ->add('translations', TranslationsType::class, [
            'fields' => [
                'promotion' => ['field_type' => EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'AdminBundle:Promotion',
                    'choice_label' => 'getName'
                ] ]
            ]
        ])
        ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

When i use the EntityType field outside the TranslationType field, its working . But when i use it within TranslationType, it dont.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar error when trying to customize the CKEditor Toolbar within an A2lix form.

The solution was not easy to find. Instead of adding a new array for the options of the class you're integrating like this:

```
 $builder
    ->add('tag', TextType::class)
    ->add('translations', TranslationsType::class, [
        'fields' => [
            'promotion' => ['field_type' => EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AdminBundle:Promotion',
                'choice_label' => 'getName'
            ] ]
        ]
    ])
```

you should try to write it like this (i.e. put the options in the array for 'promotion' directly):

```
  $builder
    ->add('tag', TextType::class)
    ->add('translations', TranslationsType::class, [
        'fields' => [
            'promotion' => ['field_type' => EntityType::class, 
                'class' => 'AdminBundle:Promotion',
                'choice_label' => 'getName',
            ] 
        ]
    ])
```